# Suggest aspects to fix in order for the question to be answered

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

I believe most questions that are unanswered are unanswered because they are either poorly written or missing a question.

It would be useful for members to be able to leave either a comment or some sort of vote as to whether the question is correctly said, which would help the original poster to correct his question. People would be able to leave points for:

- I do not understand the question
- There are informations missing
- Where is the problem?
- What have you done so far that work/doesn't work?
- etc.

This way, if the original poster notices that one aspect of his post is getting many hits, he might redo it in order to improve his chances of getting an answer.

Comment: where is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You can already leave comments inviting the OP to clarify the question. In fact, if you have sufficient reputation, you can help the OP out by clarifying the question (assuming you understand what the OP intended).

You can even win some shiny badges for this :)